# Taking average of last n elements with group by in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe df as:

```
Time    Type    Value
1/15/2019   A   109.99
1/16/2019   A   108.47
1/17/2019   A   107.71
1/18/2019   A   109.23
1/21/2019   A   109.23
1/22/2019   A   108.47
1/23/2019   A   110.75
1/24/2019   A   112.27
2/4/2019    B   172.1
2/5/2019    B   170.55
2/6/2019    B   170.55
2/7/2019    B   171.79
2/8/2019    B   172.41
2/11/2019   B   174.89
2/12/2019   B   176.15
2/13/2019   B   174.09
2/14/2019   B   171.05
```

I want to get the average of last 3 values of each type from above as follows:

```
Type Last3Avg
A    110.50
B    173.56
```

i.e. `average(108.47, 110.75, 112.27) = 110.50`, etc.

I am trying various syntax for following but not having success:

```
df.groupby('Type').ix[-3:].mean()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New way of using `nth`

```
df.groupby('Type').nth([-1,-2,-3]).Value.mean(axis=0,level=0)
Out[250]: 
Type
A    110.496667
B    173.763333
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 6):

Let's try `groupby` and `apply`. Take the last 3 rows and find their mean.

```
df.groupby('Type').apply(lambda x: x.tail(3).mean())

           Value
Type            
A     110.496667
B     173.763333
```

Similarly, you can also do

```
df.groupby('Type').tail(3).groupby('Type').mean()

           Value
Type            
A     110.496667
B     173.763333
```

Comment: Your second method requires me to change my code less. Thank you.